# Tie together multiple functions retrieving values to single end goal, jQuery/jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I realize this is going to be a long answer, so I appreciate anyone taking the time to write it out for me.

I have been struggling with this issue for the passed week, granted I haven't been coding much due to frustration over this issue!

In short what I am trying to do is from page1 with a main table dynamically created by row, click a button on each table row that takes the user to page2, clicks an item on page 2 and is prompted with a dialog box with a number input, input the number, retrieve the number input and the text value of the page2 item and add them into a subtable in the main table of the corresponding row.

I figured I'd have to use a lot of 'this' keyword to retrieve the values I want. But I'm having trouble understanding how to lay this all out.

So far I'm working with this:

```
$("#addTableRowBtn").click(function() {
    $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#firstValueSearchPage");
});

$(".addFirstValueToList").click(function() {
    $("#mainTable").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).text() + "<div class='delete ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-notext'></div></td><td><table class='secondValueTable'><tr class='secondValueTableLastRow'><td data-role='table' class='ui-responsive totalCaptionCell'>Total</td><td class='totalHoursCell'>0.00</td></tr></table></td><td class='addNewValueCell ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext'></td></tr>");
    $("body").pagecontainer("change", "index.html");
});

$("#mainTable").on("click",".addNewValueCell", function () {
    $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#secondValueSearchPage");
        $(".addValueToSubTable").click(function() {
            var textValue = $(this).text();
            $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#numberDialogPopup", function() {
                /* ??? */
            });
        $(".secondValueTable .secondValueTableLastRow", $(this).closest('tr')).before("<tr><td>" + textValue + "</td><td>" + numberValue + "</td></tr>");
        $("body").pagecontainer("change", "index.html");
    });
});
```

The #numberDialogBox contains a form with a number input where I would retrieve the numberValue from.

I realize again this is not a simple answer, I'm working with multiple functions to one end goal. If there is any resource that would explain how this could all tie together I would appreciate a link just as much. Thank-you!

EDIT:

I put together a crude 'diagram' of what I'm trying to do using pictures. The red box is the click to go to the next page. I think this makes a bit more sense. I can dynamically create the table row with textVal1, and I can navigate to Page 3 from the row button, but it's collecting the textVal2 and numberVal on the way and then adding them to the sub table in the main table's row that I'm lost on, nevermind totaling up the number value column (as you can see would be my next step).

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: If you can create a demo of your current situation, it will be easier to give you hints. Use plnkr.co to create a demo.

Comment: I added a crude picture diagram in the original post to try to better explain what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any help. I tried plnkr.co but could not find where to add jQuery mobile and for whatever reason else I couldn't get it to better help explain my situation.

Comment: Well, you can do whatever you want to _page 1_ whenever you click any button in any other page, even if _page 1_ is hidden. Just make sure it's cache/present in DOM.

Comment: something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/3aVaoJAl1jtiWn6k1bbh just do the same for the number.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. I have been able to get to the third stage of my diagram, adding rows to my main table with specified text value, such as in your plnkr example. What I need to figure out is how pressing the button on each individual row can add a different text value and number value to the sub-table of that specific row. I've tried using $(this) a lot, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax and how it all pieces together.

Comment: I want to be able to press the button on the main table row, go to a page with a list of text values, have a popup to enter in my number value, and add those specific text and number values to the sub table of the original row.

Comment: There is a way to save the value of the clicked button. Or add a class to then get back to it, do what your things then remove the class. I'll show you how tomorrow.

Comment: Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/3aVaoJAl1jtiWn6k1bbh I've made some changes in html and jquery code.